# Evaluation of complex integration from book Lars V.Ahlfors chapter 4 page 121

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

[image]${\displaystyle \int \exp(z)/z\,dz}$ over the curve $|z|=1$
I made an attempt by expressing the exponential part is series form and then we have to integrate only $1/z$ over the curve and I got the answer $2 \pi i$. Can anyone share another answer or any shortcut method to solve?

Comment: This exercise is to a chapter discussing Cauchy's integral formula. I think you are expected to use Theorem 6.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Yes....Is it possible to use that

Comment: You have dx.  Shouldn't it be dz?  In that case. $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $dz=izd\theta$ so integral is $i\int_0^{2\pi} exp(e^{i\theta})d\theta$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes sorry for mistake

Comment: By Cauchy’s integral formula isn’t it $2\pi i\cdot\exp(0)=2\pi i$?

Comment: @FShrike yes but I wished to use theorem 6 can you say how can I use that

Comment: I can’t know that unless you show us that theorem $6$ is

Comment: @FShrike i have provided that in the picture you can see them and I hope you know all the thing mentioned there

Comment: Ah. Theorem $6$ is exactly Cauchy's integral formula. Set $a=0$ and notice that you get the conditions of the theorem